# Can you tell me whats wrong with this SSE code and how to do it better?

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, x86, sse

I'm learning SSE for the first time and trying to optimise some code. I have two problems.

1. The SSE logic seems to be a little off. The code is used to resample audio but it results in just noise so its obviously wrong somewhere.
2. I think the compiler does a better job without my help.

**Update:** I realised that the initial values for pos4 and frac4 were wrong I'm update the code below. But there is still a logical error somewhere else.

// My attemp at SSE

```
typedef unsigned int ALuint;
typedef float ALfloat;

static __inline __m128 lerp_SSE( const __m128 mu, const __m128 val1, const __m128 val2 ) {
    /* val1 + (val2-val1)*mu */
    const __m128 r0 = _mm_sub_ps( val2, val1 );
    const __m128 r1 = _mm_mul_ps( mu, r0 );
    const __m128 r2 = _mm_add_ps( val1, r1 );

    return r2;
}


void Resample_lerp32_SSE(const ALfloat *data, ALuint frac,
  ALuint increment, ALfloat *RESTRICT OutBuffer, ALuint BufferSize)
{
    ALuint i;
    ALuint pos;
    ALuint pos0_tmp = 0;
    ALuint frac0_tmp = frac;

    ALuint frac0_incr = frac0_tmp + increment;
    ALuint pos1_tmp = frac0_incr>>FRACTIONBITS;
    ALuint frac1_tmp = (frac0_incr & FRACTIONMASK);

    ALuint frac1_incr = frac1_tmp + increment;
    ALuint pos2_tmp = pos1_tmp + (frac1_incr>>FRACTIONBITS);
    ALuint frac2_tmp = (frac1_incr & FRACTIONMASK);

    ALuint frac2_incr = frac2_tmp + increment;
    ALuint pos3_tmp = pos2_tmp + (frac2_incr>>FRACTIONBITS);
    ALuint frac3_tmp = (frac2_incr & FRACTIONMASK);

    __m128i frac4 = _mm_set_epi32(frac3_tmp, frac2_tmp, frac1_tmp, frac0_tmp);
    const __m128i increment4 = _mm_set1_epi32(increment);
    const __m128 fracOne4 = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f/FRACTIONONE);
    const __m128i fracMask4 = _mm_set1_epi32(FRACTIONMASK);

    __m128i pos4 = _mm_set_epi32(pos3_tmp, pos2_tmp, pos1_tmp, pos0_tmp);

    for(i = 0;i < BufferSize-3;i += 4)
    {
        __m128 val1 = _mm_set_ps(data[pos3_tmp], data[pos2_tmp], data[pos1_tmp], data[pos0_tmp]);
        __m128 val2 = _mm_set_ps(data[pos3_tmp+1], data[pos2_tmp+1], data[pos1_tmp+1], data[pos0_tmp+1]);

        __m128 mu = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_cvtepi32_ps(frac4), fracOne4);
        __m128 out = lerp_SSE(mu, val1, val2);

        _mm_store_ps(&OutBuffer[i], out);

        frac4 = _mm_add_epi32(frac4, increment4);
        pos4 = _mm_add_epi32(pos4, _mm_srli_epi32(frac4, FRACTIONBITS));
        frac4 = _mm_and_si128(frac4, fracMask4);

        pos0_tmp = _mm_extract_epi32(pos4, 0);
        pos1_tmp = _mm_extract_epi32(pos4, 1);
        pos2_tmp = _mm_extract_epi32(pos4, 2);
        pos3_tmp = _mm_extract_epi32(pos4, 3);
    }

    pos = pos0_tmp;

    for(;i < BufferSize;i++)
    {
        const ALfloat *vals = data + pos;
        OutBuffer[i] = lerp(vals[0], vals[1], frac * (1.0f/FRACTIONONE));

        frac += increment;
        pos  += frac>>FRACTIONBITS;
        frac &= FRACTIONMASK;
    }
}
```

// Plain C version

```
void Resample_lerp_C(const ALfloat *data, ALuint frac,
  ALuint increment, ALfloat *RESTRICT OutBuffer, ALuint BufferSize)
{                                                                             
    ALuint pos = 0;
    ALuint i;                                                                 

    for(i = 0;i < BufferSize+1;i++)                                           
    {                                                                         
        OutBuffer[i] = lerp32(data + pos, frac);                             

        frac += increment;                                                    
        pos  += frac>>FRACTIONBITS;                                           
        frac &= FRACTIONMASK;                                                 
    }                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Posts like these are appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RSahu: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for *working* code - the OP says that his code is not working correctly (optimisation is a secondary problem, since there is no point trying to optimise broken code).

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for pointing out the difference. I hadn't realized that.

Comment: Just to clarify the non SSE code works fine.

Comment: @Tim: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your SSE code as far as functionality is concerned - I think you'll just have to debug it in the time-honoured fashion. There are a number of performance issues with it though, particularly using `_mm_set_ps` to do gathered loads. For now just focus on fixing the code and then when it's working to the point where output matches that from the original scalar code you can post a new question where we can focus on performance issues.

Comment: @PaulR ok thanks for taking a look. I'll keep searching.

Comment: I suggest setting the increment to an "easy" value initially and single stepping through the code for a few samples - any problem with the interpolation should become apparent pretty quickly using this method. Maybe do it with the scalar code and the same data first to get the first few expected values for comparison with the SSE output.

Comment: Of course, you can still step through with a debugger to determine where calculations go "wrong".

Comment: Problem solved I was to busy double checking I was using the correct intrinsics that I didnt notice I wasnt incrementing the value by the correct amount const __m128i increment4 = _mm_set1_epi32(increment);

Needed to be:

const __m128i increment4 = _mm_set1_epi32(increment*4);

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be faster if you didn't try to vectorize the `pos` part, since you need it for addressing.  Getting data into and out of vectors an element at a time is probably slower than just doing it scalar.  Or if you need the loop counter in a vector, it's faster to have a scalar loop counter, and also update a vector loop counter.  (e.g. initialize a vector int to `{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }`, then add `{ 4, 4, 4, 4 }` to it in the loop.)

This is a really old question, so I'm not going to spend more time on it, but two `_mm_set_ps` and 4 `_mm_extract_epi32` in the loop is a clear sign of a big problem.

Your non-vector C version has a loop-carried dependency between iterations, but the dep chain doesn't actually depend on the input data.  So you should be able to get the first 4 values of `frac` into a vector, and add `4* increment` to it every time through the loop.

As far as gathering data from the input buffer, possibly you can use a vector load and then a variable-mask shuffle with a mask constructed from a `pos` vector.  Otherwise your best bet is probably to use scalar `movss / insertps` to set the vector elements from memory locations that might not be 4 contiguous floats.

Also, that's probably not a very sophisticated resampling algo.  Won't it totally ignore some input data values when downsampling?  There are several resampling libraries around, including librubberband which I know is good.  If those have a license that works for you, use them.